# How can you move (or copy) all files to a directory with the same filename prefix?

Tags: find, filenames, directory-structure, file-copy

**Using Bash**

So let's say I have a bunch of files randomly placed in a parent directory `~/src`, I want to grab all the files matching a certain suffix and move (or copy) them to a `~/dist` directory.

Let's assume for this purpose that all filenames have this naming convention:

```
<filename_prefix>.<filename_suffix>
```

I found out that this was a quick way to get all files with a particular `filename_suffix` and put them in a dist folder:

```
mkdir ~/dst
find source -name "*.xxx" -exec mv -i {} -t ~/dst \;
```

Now a step further... how can I use the output of find, in this case `filename`, and use the `filename_prefix` to generate a directory of the same name in `~/dist` and then move (or copy) all the files with that prefix into the appropriate directory?

```
mkdir ~/dst
find source -name "*.xrt,*.ini,*.moo" -exec mv -i {} -t ~/dst \;
```

Essentially, how do I change the above command (or maybe use another command), to create a structure like this

**(OUTPUT)**

```
~/dist/people/people.xrt
~/dist/games/games.xrt
~/dist/games/games.moo
~/dist/games/games.ini
~/dist/monkeys/monkeys.ini
~/dist/monkeys/monkeys.xrt
```

from a directory tree like this?

**(INPUT)**

```
~/src/xrt/people.xrt
~/src/xrt/games.xrt
~/src/conf/games.ini
~/src/pack/monkeys.xrt
~/src/e344/games.moo
~/src/e344/monkeys.moo
~/src/en-us/monkeys.ini
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It would be a hell to tell `find` what to do in this case.

Better use the shell:

```
for i in **/*.{xrt,ini,moo}; do
  FILE=$(basename "$i")
  DIR=~/dst/${FILE%.*}
  echo mkdir -p -- "$DIR"
  echo mv -i -t "$DIR" -- "$i"
done
```

Use `shopt -s globstar` to make the `**` glob work (or use zsh!).
And remove the `echo`s later if the command prints what you want.

Comment: using bash is this the same?

Comment: @codeninja `shopt -s globstar`, see my edit. If there are only two levels, you can use `*/*.*` and the snippet will work in any shell.

Answer (score 2):

cheating find command line:

```
find source -name "*.xrt,*.ini,*.moo" -exec env file={} bash -c 'base="$(basename "$file")";dir="dst/${base%.*}";mkdir -p "$dir";cp "$file" "$dir"' \;
```

actually a work around for calling bash script in find LOL.

=P

Comment: Guess what happens if there is a file which is called… `happy rm -rf /` ! This kind of code deserves a -1.

Comment: Your edit is not enough: let's say you cliked on a link and downloaded `Yay" rm -rf / "Rox0r.avi`, again there is like a problem…

Comment: (And there is no way to make this kind of substitution safe).

Comment: Ah maybe it's possible to do this differently. It seems that the following works: `-exec bash -c 'command which uses "$1"' bash '{}' ';'`. Well, it's quite pointless anyway.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez done, bash is not the only thing to use. LOL

Comment: At least it seems safe now.