# group files in folders by name

Tags: shell, files, mv

I have a folder with many files like:

```
20_1_A.xml,
20_2_A.xml,
20_3_A.xml,
...

10_1_A.xml,
10_2_A.xml,
10_3_A.xml,
...

20_1_A.csv,
20_2_A.csv,
20_3_A.csv,
...

10_1_A.csv,
10_1_A.csv,
10_3_A.csv,
...
```

I want to group the files by the first number in the name using shell commands. For example:

- all files starting with 20 inside a folder called 20 and all files starting with 10 in a folder called 10. The type of file doesn't matter.

Does anybody know how to to this? I thought of using wildcards but I don't know how…

Comment: See also [How can you move (or copy) all files to a directory with the same filename prefix?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/31045)

Comment: What about files starting with `100`? Should they go into `./10` or `./100`?

Answer (score 3):

Wildcards are the right tool. You could move all files like this:

```
for i in {10,20} # or something like $(seq 10 10 90) instead of {10,20} if you have a lot of different prefixes
do
    mkdir -p "$i" &&
      mv "$i"* "$i"/
done
```

You want `mkdir -p` so that `mkdir` doesn't complain if the target directory already exists.

Comment: Note  that `for i in {10,20}` is the same (though less portable) as `for i in 10 20`.

Answer (score 3):

```
for datei in *_*.xml *_*.csv; 
 do mkdir -p -- "${datei%%_*}" && 
    mv -- "$datei" "${datei%%_*}"
 done
```

For each file matching the patterns create a dir named by the part before the first underscore (if it doesn't already exist, `-p` option) and move the file there.

Hope this fits.

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh`:

```
mkdir_and_move() {mkdir -p -- $2:h && mv -- "$@"}
autoload zmv

zmv -P mkdir_and_move '(<->)*.(csv|xml)(#q.)' '$1/$f'
```

`<->` is a glob that matches any decimal integer (`<x-y>` is integers from `x` to `y`). `(#q.)` is a glob qualifier that selects only regular files.

Similar to what you would be doing with a loop except that `zmv` adds a few sanity checks.

Comment: One more reason to like zsh!