# Find and copy files where the destination directory is based on a part of the file name

Tags: shell, find, exec

I'm looking to do a linux sh script that

1. parse a folder to look for a certain extension
2. copy all these files in a certain folder based of a part of the file name.

Currently I succeeded to create two command lines,

One to create the folders based on a part of the file name, the only missing point is that I would prefer to create all theses folders in the "Out" folder and not in the current folder :

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f \( -name "*.xxx" -o -name "*.yyy" \) \
 | tr -s '[:blank:]' '_' \
 | cut -d"-" -f1 \
 | xargs mkdir -p
```

And the second to copy all the file found in a static folder Out :

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f \( -name "*.xxx" -o -name "*.yyy" \) -exec cp '{}' Out \
```

I do not succeed to merge both command in order to copy files in a subfolder based on its name (subfolder to be created if not existing)

Thanks for help !

Comment: A few examples of filenames and where you think they should end up would benefit the question.

Comment: 519_RU-1801013_20181217_141826_656.xxx
519_RU-1801013_20181217_143011_657.xxx
AB47 825_RU-1809008_20190723_015635_947.yyy

Comment: Could you please give at least 3 filenames and where they should go.  Please edit your question with those details.

Answer (score 2):

Here, it would be easier with dedicated file renaming tools like `prename`, `mmv` or `zsh`'s `zmv`. But if you have to use POSIX `sh` and utilities, I'd do things like:

```
find . ! -name . -prune \( -name '*.xxx' -o -name '*.yyy' \) -type f -exec sh -c '
  ret=0
  for file do
    name=${file##*/}
    dstdir=Out/$(printf "%s\n" "${name%%-*}" | tr -s "[:space:]" "[_*]")
    mkdir -p "$dstdir" &&
      cp "$file" "$dstdir/" &&
      true > "$file" || ret=$?
  done
  exit "$ret"' sh {} +
```

(also avoiding your several GNUisms).

Comment: Nice touch with `$ret`. It's usually the first thing I forget about.  Can you confirm that the snippet `tr -s "[:space:]" "[_*]"` is about replacing every space encountered by as many `_` signs and then ( `-s` ) squeezing those underscores down to 1 only ?

Comment: @Cbhihe, yes, it's the standard/POSX version of BSD/GNU's `tr -s "[:space:]" _`. `[:space:]` includes more spacing characters than `[:blank:]` (it's guaranteed to be a superset), but beware that GNU `tr` doesn't support the multibyte ones (yet)

Answer (score 0):

I'd do that in two passes:

First, create the directories as you did...

```bash
find -maxdepth 1 -type f \( -name "*.xxx" -o -name "*.yyy" \) \
| tr -s '[:blank:]' '_' \
| cut -d"-" -f1 \
| xargs mkdir -p
```

And second making use of bash brace-expansion...

```bash
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -not -name '.' -exec bash -c 'cp ${1}*.{xxx,yyy} ${1}/' _ {} \;
```

Result:

```
$ tree
.
├── 519_RU
│   ├── 519_RU-1801013_20181217_141826_656.xxx
│   └── 519_RU-1801013_20181217_143011_657.xxx
├── 519_RU-1801013_20181217_141826_656.xxx
├── 519_RU-1801013_20181217_143011_657.xxx
├── 825_RU
│   └── 825_RU-1809008_20190723_015635_947.yyy
├── 825_RU-1809008_20190723_015635_947.yyy
└── AB47
```

You could replace `in xxx yyy` with a command generating a list of extensions.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for your help, I finaly found the solution, based on another topic that helped me a lot ([Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31045/how-can-you-move-or-copy-all-files-to-a-directory-with-the-same-filename-prefi?rq=1).

Please find it below :

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f \( -name "*.xxx" -o -name "*.yyy" \) -size +0 -exec env file={} bash -c 'base="$(basename "$file" | tr -s '[:blank:]' '_' |cut -d"-" -f1)" ;dir="Out/${base%.*}";mkdir -p "$dir";cp "$file" "$dir" ; truncate "$file" -s 0 ' \;
```

Comment: If you could update the question with the requested info, we would be able to give you a better solution. It looks as if you don't actually have to use `find` at all since you know exactly what files you want to copy and where they are.  Your solution also does a lot of other things that you never said anything about in the question (like checking the size of the files and truncating them after copying them).